# Purim Torah (not in jest)

Tags: halacha, torah-study, purim

Are there sources that discuss whether or not "Purim Torah" is halachically appropriate? I know of at least one contemporary author who insists that it's מגלה פנים שלא כהלכה and a זלזול התורה, but many more Rabbis seem to be ok with it. Are these issues discussed anywhere in halachic literature?